# Android studio remove middle part from package name

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to remove the middle part from the package name.
Ex: **com.example.app** to **com.app**

I have tried few things but not able to remove the middle part of the package name without errors.

Comment: Did you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: @NaumanAfzaal Afzaal Yes, I tried that, It didn't let me remove the middle name of package.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that the only you can achieve that is this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, set `Text to find` to `com.example.app`, `Replace with` to `com.app` and hit `Find`, `All Files`.
2. After that open the directory `com` in file manager, move `app` up in hierarchy, so it becomes `com/app` and remove `example` directory.

Comment: What is the command for this in Mac? for searching in all files

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was working on the Linux machine at the time of writing, so I didn't know any Mac shortcuts. @NeeK thanks for adding this info!

Answer (score 11):

There is a much better way to do this. com.example.app >> com.app

In Android Studio,

1) Open your project pane (tab on left top) select Android option.

2) In the same pane click on the gear icon and uncheck "Compact Entity Middle Packages".

3) Expand your package hierarchy in Project pane.

4) Now drag the package app (the one you want to move) on the package com (where you want to move).

5) You will see a red boundary around the com package now drop package app.

6) A popup should appear select "Move package", next enter com package path, next select do refactor.

Done!!

**Please note, different Studio versions have different options but drag and drop method remains the same**

Comment: Wow as simple as this thank you man

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio indirectly (but easily) supports this requirement;
e.g. Change **java.X.Y.myPrecious** to **java.myPrecious** [assume packages **X** and **Y** are empty]
(a) Select *Android* from dropdown heading in *Project* window.
(b) Using the *'gear/cog'* tool uncheck *Compact Empty Middle packages*
(c) Drag **myPrecious** to **java** (be patient if necessary)
(d) *Right-click/Delete* **X**
(e) *Clean* and *Rebuild* the project making any obvious changes to the Manifest if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

click on Setting,in setting click compack Empty middle package
then click on your package :-> Refactor->Rename ->ok

Answer (score 0):

-if you package is not devided into more then 3 sub directories best way is to just rename them. Refector -> Rename -> done.

-But when you what to remove the empty one you shoud set structure to
android-> compact middle package -> now move you files to the desired folder
-> remove the empty ones now -> Done

Comment: if the package don't have files then you can easily delete, otherwise you can create other folder for all files, then delete this one

Answer (score -1):

Click with right button in your packet and find REFACTOR.Inside It you have the option Rename and after clicking a window will appear to confirm you with warnings.

Try it!

Answer (score -1):

Basically, You need to move the entire below files to precedent package.

Suppose..

Package: com.app.example.food
if you want to delete example from package.

Move com.app.example."food" directory to com."app" directory directly

Done.